# Can rolling over a Defined Contribution Plan to a Roth IRA make investment earnings tax-free while avoiding Roth contribution limits?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, retirement, rollover

My employer offers a Defined Contribution Plan (DCP) where I can contribute after-tax earnings. Investment earnings grow tax-deferred. There is an option to roll over DCP (after-tax) contributions to a Roth IRA, and Roth IRA conversion rollovers are not subject to annual Roth IRA contribution and income limits. (If there are investment earnings on the DCP contributions, you cannot roll these over to the Roth without first paying taxes on them.)

My question is, if every time I contribute to my DCP, I immediately rollover these contributions to a Roth (before these contributions generate any earnings), can I avoid the Roth contribution limits while enjoying tax-free earnings on my contributions?

Comment: Are there any company matching funds? Or any other funds such as profit sharing or a special bonus?

Comment: Not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this is why it's often called the ["Mega Backdoor Roth"](https://www.madfientist.com/after-tax-contributions/). There are still limits on after-tax contributions to DCPs, but they are much higher than the contribution limits on traditional/Roth IRA or pre-tax/Roth DCPs; for example, in 2021 the total contribution limit to a DCP is [$58,000](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/cola-increases-for-dollar-limitations-on-benefits-and-contributions) for most people.